# Does zero-kernel imply monic in Abelian categories?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, universal-property, diagram-chasing

I'm trying to learn how to perform diagram-chasing in abstract Abelian categories. Instead of an approach with some elements one have to use universal properties somehow in the proof. But I reckon the need of some lemmas...

> A category is Abelian if:
>
> - it has a zero object
> - it has all binary products and binary coproducts
> - it has all kernels and cokernels
> - every monomorphism is a kernel to some morphism
> - every epimorphism is a cokernel to some morphism

The first "lemma" that coming into my mind (though I don't really know if it is true) deals with the connection between being monic and have a kernel equal to zero.

> From the universal properties:

(1)$\quad \beta$ is a *monomorphism* if it given morphisms $m,n$ holds that
$\beta m=\beta n\implies m=n$
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    X @>m>n> B@>\beta>> B'
    \end{CD}
(2)$\quad k$ is a *kernel* to $\beta:B\to B'$ if $\beta k=0$ and for each $k'$ with
$\beta k'=0$ there is a unique morphism $\phi$ such that $k\phi=k'$
\begin{CD}
    K'@>k'>>B\\
    @V\exists!\phi VV\# @|\\
    K @>k>> B@>\beta>> B'
    \end{CD}

> How to prove that $\operatorname{ker}\beta=0\implies \beta$ is mono, using (1) and (2)?

My own approach, unfortunately, consists of staring on the diagrams above.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Actually, I don't see how we get enrichment over commutative monoids. That's the only problem, though – once we have biproducts, there's a trick for getting negatives.

Comment: Hmmm. It turns out there's a trick for getting biproducts too. See Q6 [here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~jg352/pdf/CTSheet4-2012.pdf).

Comment: @Zhen: oh, that's curious. Well, in any case, the OP needs either a stronger definition or some lemmas to get an enrichment over abelian groups.

Comment: Pity! This definition from Wikipedia seemed so gentle, but obviously it's a rather long way to prove the lemma from it. But Q6 might be a good exercise.

Comment: Thanks for the information of the problematic!

Comment: The exercise that Zhen Lin links to uses the notion of a _pseudomonomorphism_ which in this context probably means a morphism $m$ such that $mf=0$ implies $f=0$.

Comment: Pseudomonomorphisms are the subject of Q5.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Your first comment is an answer, right?

Answer (score 3):

I assume your abelian categories are also additive.

First prove that $f$ is a monomorphism if and only if $fg = 0$ implies $g = 0$ for all $g$.

Now assume $f : X \to Y$ has kernel $(0, 0 \to X)$ and suppose $g : W \to X$ with $fg = 0$. Then by (2), there is a morphism $h : W \to 0$ such that $g = 0h = 0$.